# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext locally

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm new to everything related to java/scala/maven/sbt/spark, so please bear with me.
Managed to get everything up and running, or at least so it seems when running the spark-shell locally. The SparkContext gets initialized properly and I can create RDDs.

However, when I call spark-submit locally, I get a SparkContext error.

```
%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit --master local --class example.bd.MyApp target\scala-2.12\sparkapp_2.12-1.5.5.jar
```

This is my code.

```
package example.bd
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object MyApp {
    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My first Spark application")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        println("hi everyone")
    }
}
```

These are my error logs:

```
21/10/24 18:38:45 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: {}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:302)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:343)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:516)
        ... 21 more
21/10/24 18:38:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.1.2
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: My first Spark application
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: User
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: User
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
21/10/24 18:38:45 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(User); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(User); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 56899.
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-8df572ec-4206-48ae-b517-bd56242fca4c
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MiB
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4:4040
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/C:/[path]/sparkapp/target/scala-2.12/sparkapp_2.12-1.5.5.jar at spark://LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4:56899/jars/sparkapp_2.12-1.5.5.jar with timestamp 1635093525663
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4:56899/jars/sparkapp_2.12-1.5.5.jar with timestamp 1635093525663
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4/192.168.0.175:56899 after 30 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4:56899/jars/sparkapp_2.12-1.5.5.jar to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-9c13f31f-92a7-4fc5-a87d-a0ae6410e6d2\userFiles-5ac95e31-3656-4a4d-a205-e0750c041bcb\fetchFileTemp7994667570718611461.tmp
21/10/24 18:38:46 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:1120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:1106)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$13(Executor.scala:953)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$13$adapted(Executor.scala:945)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:579)
        at example.bd.MyApp$.main(MyApp.scala:10)
        at example.bd.MyApp.main(MyApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:302)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:343)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:516)
        ... 21 more
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://LAPTOP-RKJJV5E4:4040
21/10/24 18:38:46 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:881)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2370)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:671)
        at example.bd.MyApp$.main(MyApp.scala:10)
        at example.bd.MyApp.main(MyApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
21/10/24 18:38:46 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
21/10/24 18:38:46 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:1120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:1106)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$13(Executor.scala:953)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$updateDependencies$13$adapted(Executor.scala:945)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:877)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:876)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:579)
        at example.bd.MyApp$.main(MyApp.scala:10)
        at example.bd.MyApp.main(MyApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:302)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:326)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:343)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:516)
        ... 21 more
21/10/24 18:38:47 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$stop$3(Executor.scala:332)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withContextClassLoader(Utils.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$new$2(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/10/24 18:38:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/10/24 18:38:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-ac076276-e6ab-4cfb-a153-56ad35c46d56
21/10/24 18:38:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-9c13f31f-92a7-4fc5-a87d-a0ae6410e6d2
```

As far as I can tell the errors are directly related to Hadoop not being set up, but that shouldn't be an issue given that I am trying to run it locally, no?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spark uses HDFS to store some metadata about queries. If you haven't tried already, you should set this property to a local directory path, maybe that helps. I hope that resolves `winutils` also, but that one is just `WARNING`, so maybe it'll work, let me know.

Comment: Hey Filip, thanks for your answer. I've just downloaded Hadoop and I'm trying to configure it to work with Spark. 
However, isn't spark supposed to also work with the local filesystem as well? Otherwise I can't really understand how the spark-shell worked without me having HDFS installed at all.

Comment: Also, installing HDFS makes it work, so kudos to you!
I'm still confused about the local filesystem / spark-shell shenanigans though.

Comment: What happens when you set it up to local directory path? Is there an error?

Comment: Hey @Filip, sorry about this. I don't really know what you mean by setting it up to a local directory path, could you clarify a bit and I'll check it out?

Comment: I mean you could set `hadoop.home.dir` for Spark to some local file path, for example `file://home/user/spark` instead of `hdfs://path`. I don't know if that will working, but I think it should.